# Running Outlook 2019 as another user

Tags: windows-10, runas, microsoft-outlook-2019

I am usually logged in as user A (not an admin). I have Outlook setup for user B (not an admin either). I am running Windows 10 version 1909.

When logged in as user B, everything works smoothly.

When trying to "run as" (using command line or GUI) Outlook as user B while logged in as user A, Outlook starts, I get a blue window with "Outlook Office 2019" and some text in the lower-left corner.

The text changes and reaches "Processing..." at which points nothing happens anymore. I can reduce the window or close it (which closes Outlook), but I can get Outlook to "properly start" and display the mails.

Any idea as to what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some general suggestions for outlook freeze issue, see if it's helpful to you: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/outlook-not-responding-stuck-at-processing-stopped-working-or-freezes-5c313d04-64af-4441-82d2-44e5a43eee5a